# Disabled options of one chosen dropdown which is selected in another chosen dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, multi-select, jquery-chosen

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/31/)

### Description:

1. I have two **multiselect dropdowns**(with **chosen plugin**)
   initially loaded.
2. I have an Add mitigator link to add extra dropdown.
3. Currently, If I select **option A** from **dropdown 1**, then **option A** gets disabled from **dropdown 2**.

### Requirement:

But on loadtime(loading from before) if **option A** is selected in **dropdown 1** then the **option A** is not disabled in **dropdown 2**.

Once i select anything from any dropdown,  only then does it gets disabled.

I want the selected options of one dropdown be disabled for other dropdowns even from the `loading time`

Comment: Your fiddle is odd.  You have scripts in the html section as well as the script section.... Please correct.

Comment: Need to move the fiddle code into a stack snippet on stackoverflow.  This question will be worthless when that fiddle is deleted or JSFiddle changes it's links.